# Is OpenNLP able to extract keyword from content?

Tags: nlp, opennlp

Is OpenNLP able to extract keyword from content?
If yes, how?
If no, which tool should I use?

I would like to tag content automatically.
For example.

> Jessica Chastain has revealed that a meeting has taken place with Marvel over an undisclosed role, although the star has confirmed it is not Captain Marvel.
>         “We’ve talked about aligning our forces in the future,” Chastain told MTV of her relationship with the studio. “And here’s the thing with me… If you’re going to be in a superhero movie, you only get one chance.”
>   “You’re that character forever. So why do a superhero movie and play the boring civilian?” A possible reference to Maya Hansen there? Chastain had been attached to the Iron Man 3 character before eventually dropping out on account of scheduling difficulties…
>   “I don’t want to say too much,” continues the star, “but there was one thing, there was a possibility in the future of the character becoming… And I was like, ‘I understand that, but I want to do it now!’”
>   Just who that character might be is up for interpretation, although Chastain has moved to quash subsequent rumours that she is in line to play Captain Marvel.

It should be tagged as  "superhero", "movie".

Is OpenNLP able to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OpenNLP is able to extract Named entities for you. This means anything that is the name of a person, place, organization etc. would potentially be recognized by the system.

However, what you are looking for is keyword extraction, where you want to identify relevant keywords that explain a document in the general sense. I would recommend checking out Alchemyapi.com
They have models to extract keywords, taxonomy, named entities amongst other things. The only issue is that the free version just gives you 1000 transactions per day (which might be enough for your task)